# Line Numbering with \usepackage{dramatist}?

Tags: line-numbering, dramatist

I would like to number lines every 5 lines, save the first line in each scene. This is what I have so far:

Just for clarification, I am using `\usepackage[lnps]{dramatist}`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[lnpa]{dramatist}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} 

\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\numberwithin{figure}{section} 
\numberwithin{table}{section} 



\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} 

\title{ 
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] 
\Huge \emph{Octavia} \\ 
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{a play in three acts} \\ [25pt]} 

\author{---The Authors---} 
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle 


\Character[\textbf{Octavia}---The Main Heroine]{Octavia}{Octa}
\Character[\textbf{Marc Antony}---Octavia's Husband]{Antony}{Marc}
\Character[\textbf{Cleopatra}---Queen of Ptolemaic Egypt and Lover of Marc Antony]{Cleopatra}{Cleo}
\Character[\textbf{Octavian}---Octavia's Brother]{Octavian}{Oct}
\Character[\textbf{Caesarion}---Cleopatra's Son with Julius Caesar]{Caesarion}{Caesar}
\Character[\textbf{Servius}---Octavia and Antony's Servant]{Servius}{Serve}
\Character[\textbf{Children}---Cleopatra's Children with Antony]{Children}{Child}
\Character[\textbf{Chorus}---Both Octavia's Handmaidens and the People of Egypt]{Chorus}{Chorus}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 1}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 1}{1}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 2}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 2}{2}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 3}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 3}{3}
\settowidth{\speakswidth}{\speaksfont{Frederico}\speaksdel\hspace{\speechskip}}

\DramPer

\Act{}
\Scene{Octavia's Bedchambers}

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Darkness
     \end{center}
}
\StageDir{Octavia Sits, Reclined on a Couch. Chorus of Handmaidens Listens, Half-Intently}
\begin{drama}
\Octaspeaks Years ago, Barely widowed, I was informed of my marriage to Antony. It was a hasty patch of a ruined relationship.  My brother Octavian had never gotten along with Antony, and rather than kindness, he gave him his sister.  Our relationship may have been political in its reasoning, (which marriages aren't, after all) but I can't complain.  Most women envy me for his power and riches, but I don't see the reason in that. I guess you could say we fell in love. Many of my fondest memories were when we walked together, confidently through the forum. I had no need to worry with Antony by my side. I recall one instance in particular, which I found quite humorous: we were taking our mid-day stroll, when we bumped into my brother in the Forum. Antony tensed up, as did Octavian, seemingly wanting to throw a fist or two. But I, I stepped in between the two of them and grabbed Antony by the waist, pressing his lips against mine. My brother was mortified! By then, we had even drawn quite a crowd with the people, and they burst into laughter at the sight of my brother's face. Even Antony, still begrudging the loss of a fight with Octavian, couldn't help but chuckle a bit. 

I do not hate my brother, no. We  get along quite nicely, as a matter of fact. When Antony was here, though, I did not meet up with him nearly as often as I do now. It is strange, watching your little brother slowly gain power over the Roman world. I have had my qualms with his politics, but he \emph{is} my brother; I grew up with him! I put up with his bullshit every day! Now that he is older, he has become more rational, and I do agree with his views a bit more. Though I still wish he and Antony would just get along! Oh, Octavian can be a fickle soul, and he once loved Antony as much as I do now. 
\end{drama}
\StageDir{Enter Servius}
\begin{drama}

\Servespeaks Madam, a letter for you just arrived earlier this morning.
\Octaspeaks Please, from whom is this letter? Is it my beloved Antony? I need to know!
\end{drama}
\StageDir{Servius clears his throat}
\begin{drama*}
\Servespeaks A letter from Antony, yes, this is.
\end{drama*}
\end{document}
```

I would like line numbers to the right of the prose, around 3 or 4 spaces off to the side. I would also like line numbers for verse to be in the same column.

[image]

Comment: Please compose a minimal, yet *complete* document showing us your current settings, and add it to your question. Should the numbering be to the left, to the right?

Comment: As posted it makes `! Paragraph ended before \title was complete.` just missing a `}` I suspect but please fix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, a closing brace was missing; since I added it the code in my answer I also added it to Reuben Stern's code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the drama environment, the `lnps` and `lnpa` options for numbering have no effect. To get the numbering, you can use the [`lineno`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lineno) package, with `\modulolinenumbers[5]` to get numbering each five lines; you can activate the numbering invokink `\linenumbers` (or some other form of the numbering command offered by the package); you can also control the positioning of the numbers; a little example with your current settings:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[right]{lineno} 

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} 

\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\numberwithin{figure}{section} 
\numberwithin{table}{section} 



\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} 

\title{ 
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] 
\Huge \emph{Octavia} \\ 
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{a play in three acts} \\ [25pt]} 

\author{---The Authors---} 
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle 


\Character[\textbf{Octavia}---The Main Heroine]{Octavia}{Octa}
\Character[\textbf{Marc Antony}---Octavia's Husband]{Antony}{Marc}
\Character[\textbf{Cleopatra}---Queen of Ptolemaic Egypt and Lover of Marc Antony]{Cleopatra}{Cleo}
\Character[\textbf{Octavian}---Octavia's Brother]{Octavian}{Oct}
\Character[\textbf{Caesarion}---Cleopatra's Son with Julius Caesar]{Caesarion}{Caesar}
\Character[\textbf{Servius}---Octavia and Antony's Servant]{Servius}{Serve}
\Character[\textbf{Children}---Cleopatra's Children with Antony]{Children}{Child}
\Character[\textbf{Chorus}---Both Octavia's Handmaidens and the People of Egypt]{Chorus}{Chorus}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 1}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 1}{1}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 2}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 2}{2}
\Character[\textbf{Senator 3}---Member of the Roman Senate]{Senator 3}{3}
\settowidth{\speakswidth}{\speaksfont{Frederico}\speaksdel\hspace{\speechskip}}

\DramPer

\Act{}
\Scene{Octavia's Bedchambers}

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Darkness
     \end{center}
}
\StageDir{Octavia Sits, Reclined on a Couch. Chorus of Handmaidens Listens, Half-Intently}
\begin{drama}
\linenumbers
\Octaspeaks Years ago, Barely widowed, I was informed of my marriage to Antony. It was a hasty patch of a ruined relationship.  My brother Octavian had never gotten along with Antony, and rather than kindness, he gave him his sister.  Our relationship may have been political in its reasoning, (which marriages aren't, after all) but I can't complain.  Most women envy me for his power and riches, but I don't see the reason in that. I guess you could say we fell in love. Many of my fondest memories were when we walked together, confidently through the forum. I had no need to worry with Antony by my side. I recall one instance in particular, which I found quite humorous: we were taking our mid-day stroll, when we bumped into my brother in the Forum. Antony tensed up, as did Octavian, seemingly wanting to throw a fist or two. But I, I stepped in between the two of them and grabbed Antony by the waist, pressing his lips against mine. My brother was mortified! By then, we had even drawn quite a crowd with the people, and they burst into laughter at the sight of my brother's face. Even Antony, still begrudging the loss of a fight with Octavian, couldn't help but chuckle a bit. 

I do not hate my brother, no. We  get along quite nicely, as a matter of fact. When Antony was here, though, I did not meet up with him nearly as often as I do now. It is strange, watching your little brother slowly gain power over the Roman world. I have had my qualms with his politics, but he \emph{is} my brother; I grew up with him! I put up with his bullshit every day! Now that he is older, he has become more rational, and I do agree with his views a bit more. Though I still wish he and Antony would just get along! Oh, Octavian can be a fickle soul, and he once loved Antony as much as I do now. 
\end{drama}
\StageDir{Enter Servius}
\begin{drama}
\linenumbers

\Servespeaks Madam, a letter for you just arrived earlier this morning.
\Octaspeaks Please, from whom is this letter? Is it my beloved Antony? I need to know!
\end{drama}
\StageDir{Servius clears his throat}
\begin{drama*}
\Servespeaks A letter from Antony, yes, this is.
\end{drama*}

\end{document}
```

[image]